# Need clarification on pointer incrementation

Tags: c, pointers

Please help me understand the reason the following code works the way it does:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 10;
    void *b = &a;
    int *p = b; 
    printf("%u",*p++);
    return 0;
}
```

I know the output of printf will be 10, but I'm not quite following why *p++ is 10

Here are my steps:

1) `void *b = &a;` stores the address of a in pointer b

2)  `int *p = b;` pointer p now points to the same data item as pointer b

3) `printf("%u",*p++);` is where I get confused... the dereference of pointer p is a, which is 10... isn't `*p++` basically the same as 10+1 which will be 11?

Answer (score 3):

`*p++` is essentially `*(p++)`. It evaluates to the value of `p` before it is incremented which is the address to `a`. Then you dereference it which evaluates to the value `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Variable p is a pointer to an int (pointing to a)

The expression *p dereferences the pointer, hence it's like accessing the int a directly.

Operator postfix ++ on pointer p takes precedence over the dereferencing. Therefore *p++ increments the pointer p (to whatever junk is in memory after int a) AFTER the expression is evaluated, so the dereferencing still resolves to a and that's why 10 is printed. But after the statement is run the value of p is changed. So, likely after that statement if you do printf("%u ",*p) you will get an awkward value.

If you do ++*p however, the expression is evaluated as ++ operation on the dereferenced int variable pointed by p. If you want to avoid trouble like this, when not sure, use parenthesis:

```
(*p)++
++(*p)
```

And you're making sure you are dereferencing the value and acting on it. Incrementing a pointer value is a very dangerous operation allowed by languages like C and C++, so avoid whenever possible!

Comment: @self Yeah, it wasn't very good before it was deleted, rewritten, and undeleted. Hopefully the downvoters will notice the change and remove their downvotes, improving both their rep and Jose's.

Answer (score 2):

The post-increment operator in the expression `*p++` applies to the pointer, not the value stored at that location, so the result is never 11, before **or** after it is evaluated. The expression `*p++` means: dereference `p` (get it's value) then increment `p` one location. Since `p` points to an `int`, incrementing it will move it forward `sizeof(int)` bytes . The addition does not *ever* apply to the value that `p` points to, which is 10.

However, the expression (*p)++ is different. It dereferences p (gets its value) and then increments the value in that memory location. The expression evaluates to the original value. So after executing the statement

```
int c = (*p)++;
```

the variable `c` would equal 10, while `a` would equal 11.

Answer (score 2):

`*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)`. `p++` evaluates to `p`, and *then* increments `p`, so the change won't be seen until the next reference to `p`. So `*p` is 10, `*p++` is 10  (but p now points to `&a+1`), `*++p` is undefined behavior (because `*(&a+1)` is not a valid value), `(*p)++` is 10 but changes `a` to 11, and `++*p` (or `++(*p)`) is 11 (as is `a`).

Answer (score 2):

### Why *p++ is 10 ?

> [C11: §6.5.2.4/2]: The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

The below statement

```
printf("%u",*p++);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%u",*p); /* p points to 'a' and value of `a` is 10. Hence, 10 is printed */
p = p + 1;
```

`p` is of type *pointer-to-int*. Hence, `1` is scaled to `sizeof (int)`.

As a result, p now points to an `int` at  address : `p + sizeof (int)`

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my five cents.
For incrementing value indirected via pointer you can use `++*ip` or `(*ip)++`. There is a nice explanation about parentheses in K&R book:

> The parentheses are necessary in this last example
>   `(*ip)++`; without them, them expression
>   would increment ip instead of what it points to, because
>   unary operators like * and ++ associate right to left.

And in your piece of code you got 10 because printf will print original value of variable and only after it wiil be incremented by one due of using of postfix `++` operator.